# Advance Sorting

Tags: vba, date, sorting

E.g. `06-02-24052012-22860-A`

Hi All, above is my primary key which I want to sort from the earliest date on the top, latest  date on the bottom.

06-02-`DDMMYYYY`-22860-A

All other numbers is random, where the date is at the center. Is there anyway I can do the sorting with such primary key?

Comment: what programming language?

Answer (score 1):

split with - and then use regex to match date

Answer (score 0):

With MS Access SQL:

```
SELECT t.AKey, 
       DateSerial(Mid([AKey],11,4),Mid([AKey],9,2),Mid([AKey],7,2)) AS DSort
FROM table t
ORDER BY DateSerial(Mid([AKey],11,4),Mid([AKey],9,2),Mid([AKey],7,2)) AS DSort
```